# How can I get the liked photo from a Facebook post with description "XXX liked a photo."?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Using the Facebook graph API I can get a post that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "774345031_10153960483905032", 
  "from": {
    "id": "774345031", 
    "name": "Ben Davis"
  }, 
  "story": "Ben Davis likes a photo.", 
  "story_tags": {
    "0": [
      {
        "id": "774345031", 
        "name": "Ben Davis", 
        "offset": 0, 
        "length": 9, 
        "type": "user"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "privacy": {
    "value": ""
  }, 
  "type": "status", 
  "created_time": "2014-03-25T20:47:39+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2014-03-25T20:47:39+0000"
}
```

How can I get the mentioned photo?

Comment: Can you post the text of the API query you used to get the above response?

Comment: that is an example of one of the posts I get back when I query the graph api with /me?fields=posts.limit(20)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following FQL query:

```
select pid, object_id, images from photo where pid in (select attachment.media.photo.pid from stream where post_id="774345031_10153960483905032")
```

For sure this is only working for Posts whih contain a photo reference. Be sure to gather the `read_stream` permission beforehand.